# Unity: Can't get object's z axis to lock when facing camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, rotation

I want a sprite to always face the camera, except in the Z-Axis. My sprites keep tipping left or right when I move the camera, and I can't have that.

I have been googling this for hours. I've tried transform.LookAt or Quaternion.LookRotation and manually setting the z to 0, but for whatever reason the z keeps adjusting. I've seen and tried so many solutions that feel like they should work but just don't. If it matters, my sprite is a child of another object, but trying localRotation doesn't work either. Freezing rigidbody constraints also has no effect.

The most accurate I can get it is this:

```cs
public class Billboard : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject cam;
    float minDist;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        cam = GameObject.Find("Main Camera");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        //Scale
        minDist = cam.GetComponent<CameraOrbit>().distanceMin;
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f) * (cam.GetComponent<CameraOrbit>().distance - minDist) * 1.01f / 3;

        //Direction
        transform.LookAt(cam.transform.position);
        Vector3 rot = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rot.x, rot.y, 0);

    }
}
```

With this I can get the sprite to face the camera, but the z axis refuses to stay at zero.

Comment: Please note that you should not change the Quaternion values themselves, because the complex calculation this class do. You should read unity's tutorial about quaternions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special thanks to StarManta for answering this question on the Unity Forums.

"OK, I think I see what's happening. Them looking like they're rotated is, I think, an illusion; I think they really are accurately pointing at the camera and right-side-up. But, you're treating the camera as if it has a round/fisheye projection, when it really has a rectilinear projection. Usually this doesn't matter but in this case it does. It's hard to explain exactly how this affects this, but the upshot is that, when things that are on either side of the center of the screen are set to "look towards" the camera, they actually appear to be rotated around their Y axes.

The solution to this is actually annoyingly simple: don't set the rotation to look at the camera, set it to be the same as the camera."

```
transform.rotation = cam.transform.rotation;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rotation constraints?

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RotationConstraint.html

Comment: I'm new to these. I added one, activated it, locked it, froze the z constraint. No effect. Also tried adding the camera as a source. Nothing.

Comment: Rotation constraints will not work if he is modifying the rotation via code, they only constrain them due to physic's based actions.  Where is he is directly setting the transform.rotation it will have no affect.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, where I wanted some 3d text to always look up, but rotated to the camera.
What worked for me was setting the undesired euler components to zero after applying the lookat rotation.
In your case, it would be something like this.

```
transform.LookAt(cam.transform.position);
var rot = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rot.x, rot.y, 0);
```

In case you need another z value, just replace the 0.

Comment: Did you mean transform.rotation.eulerAngles? I don't see just euler. Also, unfortunately that didn't work, z still rotates.

Comment: Ah yes, I wrote the code from the top of my head. Fixed it. Are you sure that no other component is affecting the z coordinate? This code sets the z coordinate to 0, if it doesn't stay zero, I suspect that something else is interfering. Try debugging it, test whether the eulerAngles.z is actually 0 after the code ran.

Comment: `
        transform.LookAt(cam.transform.position);
        Vector3 rot = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rot.x, rot.y, 0);
        Debug.Log("euler " + transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z);
`
This sometimes outputs zero, and sometimes outputs a number like 6.66031E-06. I don't know what else could be affecting it. The parent isn't rotating.

Comment: A number like 6.66031E-06 is just a numerical precission error. It's can be considered 0 in this case. Try removing / disabling all other scripts and check whether that solves the issue. Also check the rest of your code, do you somewhere reference this object and modify it? Do you somewhere modify its parent? Is physics active on that object?

Comment: I've disabled the script that this code is in, and the values no longer change, so I think it's safe to assume that this is the only code modifying rotation. Also the parent does not rotate once it is instantiated.

Comment: When the transform says that the z component is not 0 (also not nearly 0 like 1E-06), then something is modifying it. If it's not another script, its this script. Debuging showed you that the z coordinate is set correctly. So can you check your script for other places where the rotation is changed?

Comment: I've updated my question to include my entire script. Currently the only line that is affecting rotation is the transform.LookAt.

Comment: You are updating the local scale after you changed the world rotation. This may impact the local rotation. Try moving the scaling part above the rotation part.

Comment: No change unfortunately.

Comment: Then I'm quite at my witts end. I believe this is a very specific issue, that needs lots of debugging.  Maybe you should open a bug report, or ask on the Unity forum and provide extended scene information (hierarchy, code, etc)... Good luck

Comment: Alright, I'll see what I can do. Thanks for trying friend.